# Illegal character '^' in macro: Referencing prerequisites in a makedile in Windows

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with the following segment

```
test.exe: main.obj
    echo $^
```

I expected this to echo "main.obj" but I instead get

```
makefile(12) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '^' in macro
```

Is this a windows specific problem? How should I echo all prerequisites.

Comment: That error message is not generated by GNU Make.  Most likely you're using `nmake`.  `nmake` is a completely different program than normal POSIX `make` and you can't use POSIX makefiles with `nmake`.  You should install GNU Make and make sure that's what you're running.